# We are using an old chromium to call the Map API. And Got this error ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: mapbox

We are using an old chromium to call the Map API. And Got this error ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH.

We are not able to update our chromium this time. Any Help?

Thank you

We use this url
[https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-v9/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-v9/tiles/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D?access_token=%7BaccessToken%7D)

Answer (score 0):

So this is obviously an SSL error, and originates from using an old browser as you've identified.

Can you call the style API using http rather than https perhaps?

`http://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-v9/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}`

Comment: Oliver thank you  for your reply! 

It doesn't work because the http automatically redirects to https :(